# formatting files with awk to get it to YYYY-MM-DD,value format

Tags: awk, formatting

I want something like this:

```
date,temperature
2023-06-29,38
2023-06-29,38
```

This is as far as I have got so far(still trying)

```
>>awk -F"[[:blank:]]{2,}" '{print FILENAME,$3}' /log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-2[89]*_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log temperature
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log 37
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log temperature
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log 38
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
/log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
```

> > 

This is what the files look like that I am working with

```
 >>
    >> cat /log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-2[89]*_eNB_618159_table.log
    [2023-06-28 14:20:02] NE=eNB_618159 , USER=t828226 , USER_IP=127.0.0.1 , OPERATION=get , RESULT=OK
    NODE-PATH=samsung4g-access-enbdu/managed-element/hardware-management/digital-unit/fan
    RPC-REPLY-TABLE=
    ----------------------------------
    NE Name   NE ID        temperature
    ----------------------------------
    ATIDF     eNB_618159   37
    ----------------------------------
    ;
    
    [2023-06-29 14:20:02] NE=eNB_618159 , USER=t828226 , USER_IP=127.0.0.1 , OPERATION=get , RESULT=OK
    NODE-PATH=samsung4g-access-enbdu/managed-element/hardware-management/digital-unit/fan
    RPC-REPLY-TABLE=
    ----------------------------------
    NE Name   NE ID        temperature
    ----------------------------------
    ATIDF     eNB_618159   38
    ----------------------------------
    ;
```

These are the 2 files I am using in this example

```
>> ls -l /log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-2[89]*_eNB_618159_table.log
-rw-rw---- 1 vsm aceman 380 Jun 28 14:20 /log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-28_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
-rw-rw---- 1 vsm aceman 380 Jun 29 14:20 /log/msg/sched/4G-Fan-Temperature-JZ/2023-06-29_14:20:02_eNB_618159_table.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the leading spaces are not part of your files.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "date,temperature" }
     /RESULT=/{ date=substr($1,2) }
     /ATIDF/{ print date "," $3 }' 2023-06-2[89]*_eNB_618159_table.log
```

Output:

```
date,temperature
2023-06-28,37
2023-06-29,38
```

> **substr($1,2)**: Output `$1` from second character to last (here remove leading `[`)

Comment: tks I need to look up what ```/RESULT=/ ` `/ATIDF/`